# array / vector of base class objects/children objects/etc

Tags: c++, arrays, object, vector

Is it possible to create an array or a vector in c++ that has objects from both base class and derived classes, all in one? For example, if I have a father class , and a son derived class, can I put an object of each into an array/vector? What if I derive another class from son, can I put an objects from there in that array/vector? If it's possible, I would prefer to get an image on both ways(both with arrays and vectors).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't get your question though. Do you mean object or instance?! Elsewise I would say, you create a vector<Faster> and do something like vector.emplace(), but as I said. I don't know, what you are trying to do.

Comment: [Have you tried ?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1e6485434739a63)

Comment: @1nflktd yep, I just tried that, but I think it upcasts the derived objects to type father, so that's not good.

Comment: @Ryncops Why is it not good? Explain in more detail what the problem is

Comment: Well, each of these classes has a print() method. When I iterate through this vector print each element in the vector it prints only the data in the base class, but not the data in the derived classes. This is why I believe it upcasts... but, then again, I might be wrong because my knowledge of upcasts/downcasts is poor.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right thing (TM) to do here is to use a std::vector (or list or any other container) of std::shared_ptr objects. Then, when you pick an object from the list you can treat it generically (as a base_class object) or make him type-specific questions, i.e. try to dynamic_cast it to a specific derived type.